# How to throw an Exception/Interrupt the main UI Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

I currently have a Native thread which does the lions share of my Apps functionality.

One of the problems I'm having is that when a SIGNAL is called from the Native code the Java code is dying mid task (such as a ListAdapter which backs on Native code throwing an exception in `getView()`) as a side effect. These Native Code Errors fill the Google Console with the Java Stack Traces which are tantamount to "Native code died somewhere" (The Java Stack Traces don't describe the situation in which the Native code died).

I'm catching the Signal and calling through JNI but I'm having problems trying to figure out how to interrupt the UI thread.

The closest I can think is to try:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException();               
    }
});
```

from inside a handler but this seems to be resoundingly ignored. Can anyone tell me how else I can interrupt my Main/UI Thread.

Answer (score 0):

runOnUiThread(runnableAction) might help you.